# Kuntris in English on Gelatin

Tags: kashrut-kosher, product-recommendation

A few years ago I saw someone who wrote a *kuntris* (Torah journal) on gelatin in english. It discussed all the halachic issues with it. I think it was put out a while ago but I don't remember who put it out. Does anyone know who put it out and where I can get it?

Comment: https://www.torahmusings.com/2014/07/gelatin-halacha-recent-developments/

Comment: (It cites RJJ Journal of Halacha and Contemporary Society, Volume 30 https://www.worldcat.org/title/rjj-journal-of-halacha-and-contemporary-society-digital-disc-collection-over-50-volumes-fully-searchable-features-a-comprehensive-linked-index/oclc/213028750#borrow

Comment: @Loewian It wasn't the RJJ journal It was a Kuntis only on gelatin. but thanks for the article

Comment: [This book](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/195237006X/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_EG8V9DT7KY0XSX9YVA6X) is excellent and has a long detailed halachic analysis on gelatin, see also  [this article](https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5518) by the same author with a number of gelatin-related halachic issues being discussed